# Javascript Asynchronous Exception Handling with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, exception, promise

I'm currently working on a node.js app and I'm having the usual asynchronous code issue.

I'm implementing a service server on top of Node's HTTP module.

This server supports (express like) routes. 
For example I have code that looks like this:

```
server.any("/someRoute",function(req,resp){
    resp.end("this text is sent to clients via http")
});
```

The server needs to be able to withstand failure, I do not want to crash the whole server when there is a problem in a function passed to any. The problem occurs when I'm writing code that looks like:

```
server.any("/someRoute",function(req,resp){
    setTimeout(function(){
        throw new Error("This won't get caught");
    },100);
});
```

I don't see how I possible can catch the error here. I don't want to crash the server over one server-side glitch, instead I want to serve 500.

The only solutions I've been able to come up with are really not expressive. I've only come up with using `process.on("uncaughtException",callback)` and similar code using node 0.8 `Domains` (which is a partial remedy but Domains are currently buggy and this is still not very expressive since I end up having to create a domain for every handle).

What I would like to accomplish is binding `throw` actions from a function to a scope, the ideal solution is something like binding all thrown errors from a function to a specific handler function.

Is this possible? What is the best practice to handle errors in this case?

I'd like to emphasise that it should be able to continue serving requests after a bad requests, and restarting the server on every request or creating domains for every handler and catching their uncaught exceptions seems like a bad idea to me. Additionally - I've heard promises might be able to assist me (something about `throw` in promises), can promises aid me in this situation?

Comment: AFAIK, catching thrown exceptions from async code is impossible outside of something like domains (which sounds exaclty like "binding all thrown errors from a function to a specific handler function"); the alternative is to use the standard Node.js callback style where the first parameter is an error instead of throwing (and is in fact why this pattern is so prevalent).

Comment: I have to be able to work with code I did not write on my own. The dream solution would be something like functionName.exceptionHandler = someFunction(exception) or something of the sort.

Comment: Totally understand--but I'm not sure you'll get that very easily. You have to intercept the calls (which is what Domains attempts to do for built-in event emitters). (Perhaps some theoretical extension of JavaScript--think CoffeeScript--could do the necessary code generation for you.) The fact of the matter is, `throw`ing from asynchronous code is bad form, and for instance where it can't be helped (perhaps a `JSON.parse` fails, etc.), the `uncaughtException` event is your ticket to saving your app (although it would surely be better for the library to `catch` inside its own code).

Comment: @BrandonTilley I would appreciate your feedback on my own answer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069522/how-does-error-handling-work-in-node-js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Warning**: I would not recommend the original answer using domains, domains are being deprecated in the future, I had a lot of fun writing the original answer but I no longer believe it is too relevant. Instead - I suggest using event emitters and promises that have better error handling - here is the below example with promises instead. The promises used here are [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird):

```
Promise.try(function(){ 
    throw new Error("Something");
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err.message); // logs "Something"
});
```

With a timeout (note that we have to return the Promise.delay):

```
Promise.try(function() {
    return Promise.delay(1000).then(function(){
        throw new Error("something");
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("caught "+err.message);
});
```

With a general NodeJS funciton:

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll("fs"); // creates readFileAsync that returns promise
fs.readFileAsync("myfile.txt").then(function(content){
    console.log(content.toString()); // logs the file's contents
    // can throw here and it'll catch it
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err); // log any error from the `then` or the readFile operation
});
```

This approach is both fast and catch safe, I recommend it above the below answer which uses domains that are likely not here to stay.

---

I ended up using domains, I have created the following file I called `mistake.js` which contains the following code:

```
var domain=require("domain");
module.exports = function(func){
    var dom = domain.create();
    return { "catch" :function(errHandle){
        var args = arguments;
        dom.on("error",function(err){
            return errHandle(err);
        }).run(function(){
            func.call(null, args);
        });
        return this;
    };
};
```

Here is some example usage:

```
var atry = require("./mistake.js");

atry(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        throw "something";
    },1000);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("caught "+err);
});
```

It also works like normal catch for synchronous code

```
atry(function() {
    throw "something";
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("caught "+err);
});
```

I would appreciate some feedback on the solution

On a side note, in v 0.8 apparently when you catch the exception in the domain it still bubbles to `process.on("uncaughtException")`. I dealt with this in my `process.on("uncaughtException")` with

```
 if (typeof e !== "object" || !e["domain_thrown"]) {
```

However, the documentation suggests against `process.on("uncaughtException")` any way

Comment: I think that's quite nice--keeps all the domain creation in its own place.

Comment: Very nice, I love your idea!

Comment: I have implemented your idea in a module published on npm https://github.com/CodeCharmLtd/atry - `npm install atry`

Comment: @RushPL very nice! To be fair - the NodeJS core does not clean up after itself very well when it throws so this should mainly be used in userland code. Promises have a throw guarantee (you can throw in them!), promisified code is throw safe and ever since [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) came out they're as fast as callbacks so currently I use them in my code. It'd work very similarly too `Promise.try(function(){ return Promise.delay(30).then(function(){ throw new Error("Hi");});}).catch(function(err){ console.log(err); });`

Comment: Looks like a nice library worth checking out when designing future APIs! I think though that `atry` still may be useful when dealing with existing APIs or Node APIs - just needs a huge warning about possible reasource leakage so I will add reference to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825752/why-would-an-exception-cause-resource-leaks-in-node-js

Comment: What's this domain idea?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069522/how-does-error-handling-work-in-node-js