# Run NodeJS event loop / wait for child process to finish

Tags: node.js, event-loop

*I first tried a general description of the problem, then some more detail why the usual approaches don't work. If you would like to read these abstracted explanations go on. In the end I explain the greater problem and the specific application, so if you would rather read that, jump to "Actual application".*

I am using a node.js child-process to do some computationally intensive work. The parent process does it's work but at some point in the execution it reaches a point where it must have the information from the child process before continuing. Therefore, I am looking for a way to wait for the child-process to finish.

My current setup looks somewhat like this:

```
importantDataCalculator = fork("./runtime");
importantDataCalculator.on("message", function (msg) {
    if (msg.type === "result") {
        importantData = msg.data;
    } else if (msg.type === "error") {
        importantData = null;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unknown message from dataGenerator!");
    }
});
```

and somewhere else

```
function getImportantData() {
    while (importantData === undefined) {
        // wait for the importantDataGenerator to finish
    }

    if (importantData === null) {
        throw new Error("Data could not be generated.");
    } else {
        // we should have a proper data now
        return importantData;
    }
}
```

So when the parent process starts, it executes the first bit of code, spawning a child process to calculate the data and goes on doing it's own bit of work. When the time comes that it needs the result from the child process to continue it calls `getImportantData()`. So the idea is that `getImportantData()` blocks until the data is calculated.

However, the way I used doesn't work. I think this is due to me preventing the event loop from executing by using the while-loop. And since the Event-Loop does not execute no message from the child-process can be received and thus the condition of the while-loop can not change, making it an infinite loop.

Of course, I don't really want to use this kind of while-loop. What I would rather do is tell node.js "execute one iteration of the event loop, then get back to me". I would do this repeatedly, until the data I need was received and then continue the execution where I left of by returning from the getter.

I realize that his poses the danger of reentering the same function several times, but the module I want to use this in does almost nothing on the event loop except for waiting for this message from the child process and sending out other messages reporting it's progress, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Is there way to execute just one iteration of the event loop in Node.js? Or is there another way to achieve something similar? Or is there a completely different approach to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

The only solution I could think of so far is to change the calculation in such a way that I introduce yet another process. In this scenario, there would be the process calculating the important data, a process calculating the bits of data for which the important data is not needed and a parent process for these two, which just waits for data from the two child-processes and combines the pieces when they arrive. Since it does not have to do any computationally intensive work itself, it can just wait for events from the event loop (=messages) and react to them, forwarding the combined data as necessary and storing pieces of data that cannot be combined yet.
However this introduces yet another process and even more inter-process communication, which introduces more overhead, which I would like to avoid.

### Edit

I see that more detail is needed.

The parent process (let's call it process 1) is itself a process spawned by another process (process 0) to do some computationally intensive work. Actually, it just executes some code over which I don't have control, so I cannot make it work asynchronously. What I can do (and have done) is make the code that is executed regularly call a function to report it's progress and provided partial results. This progress report is then send back to the original process via IPC.

But in rare cases the partial results are not correct, so they have to be modified. To do so I need some data I can calculate independently from the normal calculation. However, this calculation could take several seconds; thus, I start another process (process 2) to do this calculation and provide the result to process 1, via an IPC message. Now process 1 and 2 are happily calculating there stuff, and hopefully the corrective data calculated by process 2 is finished before process 1 needs it. But sometimes one of the early results of process 1 needs to be corrected and in that case I have to wait for process 2 to finish its calculation. Blocking the event loop of process 1 is theoretically not a problem, since the main process (process 0) would not be be affected by it. The only problem is, that by preventing the further execution of code in process 1 I am also blocking the event loop, which prevents it from ever receiving the result from process 2.

So I need to somehow pause the further execution of code in process 1 without blocking the event loop. I was hoping that there was a call like `process.runEventLoopIteration` that executes an iteration of the event loop and then returns.

I would then change the code like this:

```
function getImportantData() {
    while (importantData === undefined) {
        process.runEventLoopIteration();
    }

    if (importantData === null) {
        throw new Error("Data could not be generated.");
    } else {
        // we should have a proper data now
        return importantData;
    }
}
```

thus executing the event loop until I have received the necessary data but NOT continuing the execution of the code that called getImportantData().

Basically what I'm doing in process 1 is this:

```
function callback(partialDataMessage) {
    if (partialDataMessage.needsCorrection) {
        getImportantData();
        // use data to correct message
        process.send(correctedMessage); // send corrected result to main process
    } else {
        process.send(partialDataMessage); // send unmodified result to main process
    }
}

function executeCode(code) {
    run(code, callback); // the callback will be called from time to time when the code produces new data
    // this call is synchronous, run is blocking until the calculation is finished
    // so if we reach this point we are done
    // the only way to pause the execution of the code is to NOT return from the callback 
}
```

### Actual application/implementation/problem

I need this behaviour for the following application. If you have a better approach to achieve this feel free to propose it.

I want to execute arbitrary code and be notified about what variables it changes, what functions are called, what exceptions occur etc. I also need the location of these events in the code to be able to display the gathered information in the UI next to the original code.

To achieve this, I instrument the code and insert callbacks into it. I then execute the code, wrapping the execution in a try-catch block. Whenever the callback is called with some data about the execution (e.g. a variable change) I send a message to the main process telling it about the change. This way, the user is notified about the execution of the code, while it is running. The location information for the events generated by these callbacks is added to the callback call during the instrumentation, so that is not a problem.

The problem appears, when an exception occurs. I also want to notify the user about exceptions in the tested code. Therefore, I wrapped the execution of the code in a try-catch and any exceptions that get out of the execution are caught and send to the user interface. But the location of the errors is not correct. An Error object created by node.js has a complete call stack so it knows where it occurred. But this location if relative to the instrumented code, so I cannot use this location information as is, to display the error next to the original code. I need to transform this location in the instrumented code into a location in the original code. To do so, after instrumenting the code, I calculate a [source map](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map) to map locations in the instrumented code to locations in the original code. However, this calculation might take several seconds. So, I figured, I would start a child process to calculate the source map, while the execution of the instrumented code is already started. Then, when an exception occurs, I check whether the source map has already been calculated, and if it hasn't I wait for the calculation to finish to be able to correct the location.

Since the code to be executed and watched can be completely arbitrary I cannot trivially rewrite it to be asynchronous. I only know that it calls the provided callback, because I instrumented the code to do so. I also cannot just store the message and return to continue the execution of the code, checking back during the next call whether the source map has been finished, because continuing the execution of the code would also block the event-loop, preventing the calculated source map from ever being received in the execution process. Or if it is received, then only after the code to execute has completely finished, which could be quite late or never (if the code to execute contains an infinite loop). But before I receive the sourceMap I cannot send further updates about the execution state. Combined, this means I would only be able to send the corrected progress messages after the code to execute has finished (which might be never) which completely defeats the purpose of the program (to enable the programmer to watch what the code does, while it executes).

Temporarily surrendering control to the event loop would solve this problem. However, that does not seem to be possible. The other idea I have is to introduce a third process which controls both the execution process and the sourceMapGeneration process. It receives progress messages from the execution process and if any of the messages needs correction it waits for the sourceMapGeneration process. Since the processes are independent, the controlling process can store the received messages and wait for the sourceMapGeneration process while the execution process continues executing, and as soon as it receives the source map, it corrects the messages and sends all of them off.

However, this would not only require yet another process (overhead) it also means I have to transfer the code once more between processes and since the code can have thousands of line that in itself can take some time, so I would like to move it around as little as possible.

I hope this explains, why I cannot and didn't use the usual "asynchronous callback" approach.

Comment: Are [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) an option? Fibers let you do that (sleep, yield, run and pause) and seem like a good approach to what you're trying to do. (Check the examples out)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Fibers sound like they fit my problem perfectly. I'll try it and report back. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Let me know if Fibers work out and if they do I can formulate it into an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Fibers work like a charm. They do exactly what I want. I ran into some others problems due to the event loop now executing while I'm in the middle of a process report, but I think that's another problem with my code.

Comment: If fibers work, you may want to check also wait.for, based on fibers: https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a *third* ( :) ) solution to your problem after you clarified what behavior you seek I suggest using [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).

Fibers let you do [co-routines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) in nodejs. Coroutines are functions that allow multiple entry/exit points. This means you will be able to yield control and resume it as you please.

Here is a `sleep` function from the official documentation that does exactly that, sleep for a given amount of time and perform actions.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    setTimeout(function() {
        fiber.run();
    }, ms);
    Fiber.yield();
}

Fiber(function() {
    console.log('wait... ' + new Date);
    sleep(1000);
    console.log('ok... ' + new Date);
}).run();
console.log('back in main');
```

You can place the code that does the waiting for the resource in a function, causing it to yield and then run again when the task is done.

For example, adapting your example from the question:

```
var pausedExecution, importantData;
function getImportantData() {
    while (importantData === undefined) {
        pausedExecution = Fiber.current;
        Fiber.yield();
        pausedExecution = undefined;
    }

    if (importantData === null) {
        throw new Error("Data could not be generated.");
    } else {
        // we should have proper data now
        return importantData;
    }
}

function callback(partialDataMessage) {
    if (partialDataMessage.needsCorrection) {
        var theData = getImportantData();
        // use data to correct message
        process.send(correctedMessage); // send corrected result to main process
    } else {
        process.send(partialDataMessage); // send unmodified result to main process
    }
}

function executeCode(code) {
    // setup child process to calculate the data
    importantDataCalculator = fork("./runtime");
    importantDataCalculator.on("message", function (msg) {
        if (msg.type === "result") {
            importantData = msg.data;
        } else if (msg.type === "error") {
            importantData = null;
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unknown message from dataGenerator!");
        }

        if (pausedExecution) {
            // execution is waiting for the data
            pausedExecution.run();
        }
    });


    // wrap the execution of the code in a Fiber, so it can be paused
    Fiber(function () {
        runCodeWithCallback(code, callback); // the callback will be called from time to time when the code produces new data
        // this callback is synchronous and blocking,
        // but it will yield control to the event loop if it has to wait for the child-process to finish
    }).run();
}
```

Good luck! I always say it is better to solve one problem in 3 ways than solving 3 problems the same way. I'm glad we were able to work out something that worked for you. Admittingly, this was a pretty interesting question.

Answer (score 5):

The rule of asynchronous programming is, once you've entered asynchronous code, you must continue to use asynchronous code. While you can continue to call the function over and over via `setImmediate` or something of the sort, you still have the issue that you're trying to `return` from an asynchronous process.

Without knowing more about your program, I can't tell you exactly how you should structure it, but by and large the way to "return" data from a process that involves asynchronous code is to pass in a callback; perhaps this will put you on the right track:

```
function getImportantData(callback) {
    importantDataCalculator = fork("./runtime");
    importantDataCalculator.on("message", function (msg) {
        if (msg.type === "result") {
            callback(null, msg.data);
        } else if (msg.type === "error") {
            callback(new Error("Data could not be generated."));
        } else {
            callback(new Error("Unknown message from sourceMapGenerator!"));
        }
    });
}
```

You would then use this function like this:

```
getImportantData(function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        // handle the error somehow
    } else {
        // `data` is the data from the forked process
    }
});
```

I talk about this in a bit more detail in one of my screencasts, [Thinking Asynchronously](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously).

Comment: I would use callbacks if I could. The problem I have is that the parent process does some extensive computations itself but regularly calls a specific function to report progress. In some cases to correctly report the progress, the data from the child process is needed, so I need to make sure that I get this data before returning from the report-function and thus letting the parent process continue it's execution. I'll edit my question to explain that in more detail.

Comment: This kind of logic can (and should) be written in an asynchronous style; trying to go against it is going to make programming in Node very difficult and awkward. Constructs like [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/) or [flow control libraries with async versions of things like `while`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) can help, though does require thinking about the flow of your logic in a very different way.

Answer (score 2):

What you are running into is a very common scenario that skilled programmers who are starting with nodejs often struggle with.

You're correct. You can't do this the way you are attempting (loop).

The main process in node.js is single threaded and you *are* blocking the event loop.

The simplest way to resolve this is something like:

```
function getImportantData() {
    if(importantData === undefined){ // not set yet
        setImmediate(getImportantData); // try again on the next event loop cycle
        return; //stop this attempt
    }

    if (importantData === null) {
        throw new Error("Data could not be generated.");
    } else {
        // we should have a proper data now
        return importantData;
    }
}
```

What we are doing, is that the function is re-attempting to process the data on the next iteration of the event loop using [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg).

This introduces a new problem though, your function *returns* a value. Since it will not be ready, the value you are returning is undefined. So you *have* to code *reactively*. You need to tell your code what to do *when* the data arrives.

This is typically done in node with a callback

```
function getImportantData(err,whenDone) {
    if(importantData === undefined){ // not set yet
        setImmediate(getImportantData.bind(null,whenDone)); // try again on the next event loop cycle
        return; //stop this attempt
    }

    if (importantData === null) {
        err("Data could not be generated.");
    } else {
        // we should have a proper data now
        whenDone(importantData);
    }
}
```

This can be used in the following way

```
getImportantData(function(err){
    throw new Error(err); // error handling function callback
}, function(data){ //this is whenDone in our case
    //perform actions on the important data
})
```

Comment: I would suggest not using `setImmediate` at all and use either callback passing or Promises instead. `setImmediate` feels like trying to make an asynchronous operation perform a bit like a synchronous one.

Comment: @robertklep I _completely_ agree, good comment. The optimal thing would be to call getImportantData from within the callback of "message" or to use events.

Comment: @robertklep Actually, I think that's what I want. Do something asynchronously, but when it's not ready in time wait for it as if it was a synchronous call.

Comment: As far as I understand it that's roughly the same approach Brandon Tilley proposed. I'll edit the question to explain why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @JoachimKurz this is _not_ the same solution Brandon suggested. This one checks if the data changed on every iteration of the event loop and isn't dependent on being aware of `importantDataCalculator` it needs no access to it and is the asynchronous equivalent of your synchronous code with the while loop

Comment: Agreed; this is how you'd go about something like a `while` loop asynchronously and is a good method. It sounds like you may still need to rethink how the main part of your program uses `getImportantData`--it's going to *need* to be asynchronous (e.g. you can't just wait for a return).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You are right, there are important differences. What I meant by "roughly the same" is that in both approaches the getImportantData() function returns before the data has been recevied. But I need to prevent this.

Comment: @JoachimKurz You __CAN'T__ prevent this.  the event on `importantDataCalculator` won't fire until it is given a chance to, which means the code _has_ to execute (and finish executing) first. This is _fundamental_ to how nodejs works. It also makes a _lot_ of sense since it means you code _reactively_, you react to events.

Comment: @Brandon I understand your aversion against me not using an asynchronous approach. It's not nice and clean and asynchronous code. But I cannot make the code using getImportantData() asynchronous because I do not control it, it's just given to the process to be executed in the background. I only know that it calls a callback I gave to it from time to time, so my only chance to pause it's execution is to not return from the callback. And I need to pause it's execution because it changes the partial data the callback was given if it continues.

Comment: @Benjamin if that really isn't possible with node, that's a bit sad, but fine. I just wanted to know whether I'm missing something or there really is no way to do that. For example, in Objective-C/Cocoa you also have an event loop but there is a method `[NSRunLoop runUntil:timestamp]` that causes the runloop to run until the given time and only returns after that. I am looking for s.th. like that in node.js.

Comment: @JoachimKurz Pausing the execution in nodejs (also known as "blocking") is the _worst possible thing_ you can do. Seriously, the motto of the framework is "You rock when you don't block". What you are attempting not only goes against the framework or the language, it's _impossible_ by design.

Comment: @JoachimKurz Oh, it's _possible_ to wait for a time, that's because the timer is independent of nodejs itself, that's irrelevant though. Instead of trying to fight _against_ the principles of the framework try to _adopt_ them. Node is a _really_ powerful technology, what you're trying to do goes _against_ it. What you are asking for is very possible with nodejs, either the way mentioned in my solution or more optimally in the way Brandon suggested, it just requires a different way-of-thought. Instead of telling your program 'what to do serially' you tell it how to _react_

Comment: @Benjamin I'm aware that I am somewhat abusing node.js here, that's why I use a separate process, to not actually block the main node process. There might be a misunderstanding when I say "pause" the execution. I want to pause it to be able to run the event loop. So it's actually a pause to be non-blocking. In this scenario I have reached a state where my computation can't continue, but I also cannot reasonably save all the intermediate data to continue at a later point in time. So I need the complete stack, freeze it, and let the event loop execute for some time.

Comment: @BrandonTilley & Benjamin: I edited the question again to describe the actual problem where I need this (see "Actual Application" heading), to better show why I think the usual "asynchronous callback" approach doesn't work. Thanks for your help and explaining that this cannot be done with node.js. That's all I wanted to know.

Comment: Interesting; and definitely, this heavy instrumentation of arbitrary code is a unique scenario. Very interested in what you come up with!

Answer (score 1):

Your question (updated) is very interesting, it appears to be closely related to a problem I had with asynchronously catching exceptions. (Also Brandon and Ihad an interesting discussion with me about it! It's a small world)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301839/javascript-asynchronous-exception-handling-with-node-js) on how to catch exceptions asynchronously. The key concept is that you can use (assuming nodejs 0.8+) [nodejs domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) to constrain the scope of an exception.

This will allow you to easily get the location of the exception since you can surround asynchronous blocks with `atry/catch`. I think this should solve the bigger issue here.

You can find the relevant code in the linked question. The usage is something like:

```
atry(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        throw "something";
    },1000);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("caught "+err);
});
```

Since you have access to the scope of `atry` you can get the stack trace there which would let you skip the more complicated source-map usage.

Good luck!

Comment: This is actually also very interesting and also relevant to the more general problem, thanks. However, I think we might have a different understanding of "location". This approach enables me to catch asynchronous exception and find the function (location) that threw them. However, what I mean by location is the exact line and column the exception was thrown at, to be able to display it in the UI at that location. I think this approach does not help me there, am I right? Still, I can probably make use of domains anyway.