# uncaughtException in await Promise even in try and catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hello i'm encounter an issue i don't understand:

i'm having an uncaught error in my nodejs application, that I can't catch even in a try...catch sentence.
I'm using mongoose 5, error not occur in above version, so I will update but I want to understand why my error is not catch here:

```js
try {
    const data = await action.find({
        _id: id,
    }).populate({
        path: "child",
        match: (parent) => ({
            property: test[undefined].property
        })
    });
} catch (e) {
   console.log("error happen"); 
}
```

I know i'll get an error due to the test[undefined].property, and console log error happen,
but instead i get an uncaught error :

```js
/mongodb/lib/utils.js:113
      throw err;
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'program')
```

I don't understand why it's not actually catch by my try..catch.

---

Edit: Response from @jfriend00 is okay.

So I tried:

```js
    try {
        const data = await action.find({
            _id: id,
        }).populate({
            path: "child",
            match: (parent) => {
                try {
                    return ({ property: test[undefined].property })
                } catch (e) {
                    throw new Error("callbackFail");
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
       console.log("An error occurred.");
    }
```

It's not working because, as explained, the error is not properly propagated.

But I can resolve it with this:

```js
    const error = [];
    const data = await action.find({
        _id: id,
    }).populate({
        path: "child",
        match: (parent) => {
            try {
                return ({ property: test[undefined].property });
            } catch (e) {
                error.push(e);
            }
        }
    });
    if(error.length > 0) {
        throw new Error("An error occurred in the callback", error);
    }
```

Obviously, I don't like this solution and I'm a bit skeptical about how to safely provide my callback when using an external library. If someone has a better solution, please share it.

Comment: The error seems to be within util.js; you're likely not passing the expected variables to a function in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exceptions thrown in asynchronous javascript not caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823205/exceptions-thrown-in-asynchronous-javascript-not-caught)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I'm not sure, I have an await before my call of action.find

Comment: The `await` does not make the execution synchronous, therefore the reasoning of the answer to the quoted question still applies.

Comment: @mykaf I know the error comme from utils.js, the issue here is that my catch is not trigger, and my error become an uncaughtException/unhandledRejection.
My nodejs will treat it as and uncaught despite the fact I try catch this function.

Comment: the await function will wait my promise to resolve or reject.From my understanding here my promise throw an error which will create a rejection, this rejection should be catch by my try..catch ?

Comment: You should catch your promise itself instead of wrapping it - so just sdd `.catch( console.log )` and see if that helps identify it. But the place the error is occurring is not included in the code posted.

Comment: @somethinghere I understand that the specific location of the error isn't included here, and that's precisely the issue. The error occurs in an external library that my client uses. My concern is ensuring that if an error occurs, it will be caught and not handled by my process.on("uncaughtException"). 
Even when using .catch(console.log), I still encounter an uncaughtException.
And I know my match function contain an error here but it's only for my exemple.

Comment: I would argue that this is a mongoose/mongodb bug. You should report that exceptions from `match` do not lead to the query promise being rejected.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a mongoose issue. It's resolve on above version. I plan to upgrade, but I was looking to find a way to avoid trouble like that in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (or improper design) in the database code.  You're supplying a `match` callback that the database will call at some time of its choosing (asynchronously) in the processing of the `.populate()` method.  When it gets an exception from calling that callback (deep down in the database code where it called the callback), it is NOT propagating that error back to the `action.find(...).populate(...)` promise and thus can't be caught by your `await` and `try/catch`.

Remember this is an asynchronous error so it won't be caught synchronously by your `try/catch`.  The only way for your `try/catch` to catch an asynchronous error is for the DB to catch it when it happens and turn it into rejecting the promise that was originally returned by the DB call.

Comment: So, based on what you explained, if I handle the async action.find(...).populate(...) with then and catch, I will catch the error. However, I still encounter an uncaught error (with mongoose 5 only).
```action.find(...).populate(...).then(() => // do someStuff).catch(e => treat error) ```

Why isn't my error being treated? In what scenario can the callback from the match throw an error that is not caught by my .catch?

Comment: @MaskedHawk - No, you apparently did not understand what I wrote in my answer - please read it again and ask questions about anything you do not understand.  This is a problem inside the database code.  Your callback (when they call it) is throwing an asynchronous exception that is NOT turned into a promise rejection by the database code.  There is no way for you to catch it from outside because it's asynchronous and is not channeled into a promise rejection.  You will have to make sure that you do not throw in the callback or crack open the database code and fix it.

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I thought. So to avoid think like that when you use an external library you doesn't have any solution other than a process.on

Comment: @MaskedHawk - Well, you can catch your own synchronous exceptions in the callback to make sure they don't get back to the database and convert them into whatever is appropriate for the callback to return.  If the callback is coming from some other code, you can wrap their callback in your own callback that has a `try/catch` so you keep a synchronous exception from getting back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

### Exception Handling in Asynchronous Code

As you can see, the code is multilevel, i.e. multiple nesting of functions. And if you are trying to handle the exceptions, you should consider the levels appropriately.

- You can handle an exception in the same level
- Or pass the exception to the outer level by **return**ing it.

  ```
    try {
    const data = await action.find({
        _id: id,
    }).populate({
        path: "child",
        match: (parent) => {
            try {
                return {
                    property: test[undefined].property
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error in match function:", error);
                return {}; // or any default value
            }
        }
    });
     } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error happened:", e);
     }
  ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Still get an error not catch. And I don't understand why